# Excel: For A1, find the highest subsequent cell before a cell of <A1 is found

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, lookup

I have column of fluctuating prices over time in column A, lets say the price of a particular stock for arguments sake.

In column B I want to know how high the price went, from that point, before it became less than the current amount.

So I'm thinking I need a formula that loops through all the subsequent cells until a cell < A1 is found, of all the cells in this range, print the highest.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks :)

Comment: Please mock up some data and expected output and put that in the original question using edit.

Comment: So if you had the values 3, 5, 4, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8, 7, 1 and your 'trigger' value was 8, the answer would be 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimal working example. 
Suppose the 
prices are in `C5:C23`, then this 
[array formula](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) 
in `D5`:

```
=MAX(INDIRECT("C"&ROW()&":C"&(ROW()+MATCH(-1,SIGN(C5:$C$23-C5),FALSE)-2)))
```

copied down results in:

[image]

Note, that `#N/A` errors are meaningful, they signal that 
below there is no price lower than that 
in column `C` on the left of the cell with `#N/A`.

** Edit ** Comments

[image]

The key point is to locate a row with the price,
that is less than in the current row (`C5`).
A "drop index" - the number of rows from the current row 
until the row where the price is less. A function

```
=MATCH(-1,SIGN(C5:$C$23-C5),FALSE)
```

returns the number ot the row (counting the current row as `1`)
for which it finds the first exact match (`-1`) 
in the array, which is populated
with the signs of difference 
between the array of prices below (`C5:$C$23`)
and the current price (`C5`).

Given that "drop index", it's simple 
to construct a text reference of the range before drop:

```
=("C"&ROW()&":C"&(ROW()+MATCH(-1,SIGN(C5:$C$23-C5),FALSE)-2))
```

and then use `INDIRECT()` to convert this text into reference
and find the desired maximum with `MAX()`.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I'm just trying to get my head around the finer points of your answer, but I can see that it does what I want.